# how can I prevent apps from opening new windows in "full-window" mode?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

With almost every application I use, if I ask for a new window, it is in "maximized" mode. I do not want this, so I need to click on the button up in the window title bar next to the close button, the "maximize/restore" button.

Rather than opening a new window and then, 99.9% of the time, clicking on that button, I would like this to be the default. How do I set this?

Comment: You may want to replace the term "full-window" by "maximized". That is the correct term and will be readily understood. Use "Edit" and edit your question and title.

Comment: I believe, the middle button might be called either "Restore" or "Maximize" depending on the window state. When it's not maximized, then the middle button's label is "Maximize", when it's maximized, it's "Restore down".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As such, user control on window placement and size in Linux is limited. However, usually, a window size is "remembered". There is an exception, where large windows automatically are maximized by the desktop. It could be that this is the cause of the issue you are facing.

This can be turned off, but the setting is not exposed to the user. So you will need to open your terminal and change the setting using a command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize false
```

Copy and paste this command in the terminal, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute it.

To undo, i.e., reset the setting to default (`auto-maximize true`), execute:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize
```

Comment: Related question: I would like the image viewer in stock Ubuntu, called "Eye of the gnome" or EOG, to open with maximized window all the time; meanwhile, I wish that other programs would not be impacted by this setting, just EOG. My `org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize` had been and is on `false`. I have not found opening in maximized state in EOG's preferences, neither on its GUI, neither in gsettings. Could I still auto-maximize only EOG windows somehow?

Comment: @Levente, feel free to open a question, but as far as I know, devilspie/devilspie2 is the only option for this - and works only on Xorg. There is little control on window size and position, and we essentially depend on whether an application developer exposes something or not. eog has a `--fullscreen` command line option, but not a maximize option.

Comment: Wow. So so so much better. Much thanx.